# Capturing the whole world with MKMapSnapshotter

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapsnapshotter

I am trying to get an image of the whole world with the MKMapSnapshotter Api for iOS. 
It doesn't matter whether I set the MKMapSnapshotterOptions's mapRect to MKMapRectWorld or the region to Span(180,360) it always creates an image from the edge of south america to Asia  and from the middle of Europe to the end of Africa.

I also tried to change the size of the MKMapSnapshotterOptions.

Is there a way to capture the whole world?

Thanks, Leo

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @BradMoore it seams there is no way but to capture the map twice and combine both images

Comment: I am ok with this I guess.